# Django superuser doesn't have permission to delete models

Tags: python, django, model, permissions, superuser

I am working on upgrading a Django website from Django 1.8 to Django 2.2 and have come across a problem when trying to delete an object from the Django admin changelist view. When I try to delete an object, I am shown a screen with the words "Deleting the selected Records would result in deleting related objects, but your account doesn't have permission to delete the following types of objects". The problem is, I am a superuser and should have permission to delete any object I want, or so I thought.

I have read a decent amount of documentation on Django upgrades and permissions of superusers, however I haven't stumbled across anything that helps me (I could be missing something though). I have tried creating a new superuser just in case, still the same message occurs though. Anyway, Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Note: I can't show any code because I am working for a company and I signed an NDA. Just some help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a package, https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian. Which allow you to restrict permission on your model object. That might make you unable to delete models. I might need to take at the modeladmin also, make sure that there is no locked action in there.

Comment: check if the `has_delete_permission` method has been overridden in the model admin.

Comment: Thanks everyone! dirkgroten was right and it turns out the has_delete_permission was overridden! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15):

For anyone else who stumbles across this problem, dirkgroten was right and it turns out the has_delete_permission was overridden! Thanks for your help dirkgroten!

Answer (score 0):

**OPENEDX**  If You are facing This issue then do this thing from the backend.

**Cannot delete user
Deleting the selected user would result in deleting related objects, but your account doesn't have permission to delete the following types of objects:
course enrollment**

Open Mysql In EDX server like AWS
then
get user id based on username
then student_courseenrollment delete from this user

Example

```
select id from auth_user where username = 'exampleusername'

delete from student_courseenrollment where user_id = get user_id from 1 query set;

like delete from student_courseenrollment where user_id = 123;
```